# How to convert aggregated data to narrow 2 columns table by the first column of numbers

Tags: text-processing

I have a big data with rows like this:

```
0   1 5 6 4
1   4 5 2 3
5   4 5 6 7
```

This data is in txt format
And I want to create new file and convert this data into 2 columns like this:

```
0 1
0 5
0 6
0 4
1 4
1 5
1 2
1 3
5 4
5 5
5 6
5 7
```

I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question to add more details: How are the fields separated - spaces, tabs, or a combination? How dou you want the output file to be delimited - the same as the input? Are there always four "value" columns after the first "field" column? Can there be empty lines or lines with only the first column?

Comment: Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Please don't things like "update", "edit", "solved" etc to the question titles

Answer (score 4):

Awk solution

An awk executable file `conv_table.awk`:

```c
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

{
    # for all fields after the first column
    for (idx = 2; idx <= NF; idx++) {
        # print first column followed by another valued column
        print $1, $idx
    }
}
```

Executable with a command like that:

```bash
chmod 755 conv_table.awk
```

Executed like that:

```bash
./conv_table.awk table.txt > output.txt
```

One line version:

```bash
awk '{for(idx=2;idx<=NF;idx++){print $1,$idx}}' table.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'for lines.map(*.words) {Map.new(.[0] => .[1..*-1]).invert.map(*.antipairs.put)};'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne 'Map.new(.[0] => .[1..*-1]).invert.map(*.antipairs.put) given .words;'
```

Sample Input:

```
0   1 5 6 4
1   4 5 2 3
5   4 5 6 7
```

Sample Output:

```
0   1
0   5
0   6
0   4
1   4
1   5
1   2
1   3
5   4
5   5
5   6
5   7
```

An advantage of using Raku is built-in `Hash` (mutable) and `Map` (immutable hash) functionalities. Above, linewise input is broken on whitespace into `words`. The first element `.[0]` is used as a key with the remainder `.[1..*-1]` as value. (FYI, the `=>` "fat arrow" constructs a key/value pair).

Once in a `Map` object, each line of input essentially looks like the following:

```perl
key => [val1 val2 val3 val4]
```

This object can be re-arranged into the desired output. First the object is `invert`ed to expand each structure into the following:

```perl
(val1 => key) (val2 => key) (val3 => key) (val4 => key)
```

Second, `antipairs` is used to exchange the keys/values:

```perl
(key => val1) (key => val2) (key => val3) (key => val4)
```

Finally, the data structure is iterated over to out`put` a single key/value pair per line (tab-separated).

https://docs.raku.org/type/Hash#Routines_supplied_by_class_Map
https://raku.org

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the post so it is now clear what I am looking for. I hope you could help me with that too.

Comment: That's a different question. I think you need to revert your Sample Input and Sample Output to the original values that you posted, and post another Question. Meanwhile, you can consider accepting one of the Answers posted here.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> mawk 'sub("^\n*",substr(_,OFS="\n"$!_" ",$!_=_),$!(NF=NF))'
> ```

```
0 1
0 5
0 6
0 4
1 4
1 5
1 2
1 3
5 4
5 5
5 6
5 7
```